# RestKit - Nil being mapped in nested object for relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I'm getting the following JSON from my server endpoint:

```
{
   (...),
   "comments":[
      {
         "user":{
            "account":"free",
            "name":"BrucWayne",
            "counter":{
               "pictures":10,
               "following":0,
               "followers":0,
               "tags":0
            },
            "id":"QYgZb"
         },
         "text":"How are you?",
         "date":"2014-04-28T16:22:47+0200"
      },
      {
         "user":{
            "account":"free",
            "name":"DevAbdul",
            "counter":{
               "pictures":19,
               "following":0,
               "followers":0,
               "tags":1
            },
            "id":"AbADE"
         },
         "text":"ALA_MA_KOTA2",
         "date":"2014-04-28T16:25:10+0200"
      }
   ]
    ,(...)
}
```

I would like to have the comments objects saved into CoreData structure with the correct relationships perserved. I have the `Comment` and `User` objects models defined as an `NSManagedObject` instance in my *.xcdatamodel file:

Comment:

[image]

User:

[image]

Here is my mapping code for the Comments object:

```
-(void) mapComment
{
     commentsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Comment" inManagedObjectStore:[self managedObjectStore]];
    [commentsMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"date",@"text"]];
    [commentsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"text" : @"text",
                                                          @"@metadata.routing.parameters.pictureId" : @"pictureId",
                                                          @"user.id" : @"userId",
                                                          @"user.name" :@"userName",
                                                                 @"date" : @"date"}];

    [commentsMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"user" connectedBy:@"userId"];
    [commentsMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"picture" connectedBy:@"pictureId"];



    RKResponseDescriptor *commentShutReponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:commentsMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/v1/pictures/:pictureId/comments" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [[self objectManager] addResponseDescriptor:commentReponseDescriptor];

     RKObjectMapping *commentRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [commentRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"text" : @"text"}];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:commentRequestMapping objectClass:[Comment class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    [self.objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];


    //Routes
    RKRoute *commentPictureRelationshipRoute = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[Comment class] pathPattern:@"/v1/pictures/:pictureId/comments" method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    [[[[self objectManager] router] routeSet] addRoute:commentPictureRelationshipRoute];
}
```

The problem that I have with this configuration is that the mapping doesn't work as expected. I've managed to have the `Picture` object mapped correctly but unfortunately i can't get RestKit to map the `User` object. All of the user references are equal to `nil` right after being parsed by RestKit. I would like to configure the relationship such that the user object is correctly recognized and mapped in CoreData as a new User object with the right relationship between itself and the Comment instance.
I would like to also mention that this relationship is a One-To-Many relationship.

Comment: So the problem is that the users don't exist before the request and you want to both create and link them at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

What you have currently is fine for the comment and connection.

What you need to add is a new mapping for `User` and a new response descriptor such that the Users can be processed. Then, once both users and comments have been mapped the connections will be made.

The only important piece of information is the key path to use on the response descriptor which should be `comments.user` to drill down to the correct level in the source data to perform the mapping.